# Make a redirect page that takes the user to one of the 5 forms (has to be random)

Tags: python, html, forms, redirect, cgi

So I am learning CGI programming with Python and i need to create some forms that ask input from the users and use the input to display some results. I will have to create five different forms (hence different results) and I want to have a "play again" button on the result page so that when users click on it they can be directed to one of the five forms. I read a lot on redirecting but in my case, I can't just put an url because I want a random page generated. How can I do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: How is it set up currently? Is the form posting to the python script, and the python script is redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python module `random`.

```
import random
urls = [
    'form1.html',
    'form2.html',
    'form3.html',
    'form4.html',
    'form5.html',
]
redirect_to = random.choice(urls)

# then do your redirection stuff
```

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put this? in the .cgi file?

Comment: If I understand how you have it set up, then yes.  I haven't actually used python as a cgi before, so this is just some python code that will let you pick a random value from a list of values.